# Is it possible to save a folder with SFTP?

Tags: php, sftp

I've uploaded a folder with extension `.zip` via a web interface and I want to save via SFTP so that a perl script can retrieve the folder, unzip it, and execute some instructions.

I've found these two utilities, `ssh2_scp_send` and `ssh2_scp_recv`, but they are related to files, not folders. Can anyone help?

Comment: A folder with a ".zip" extension is **not** a folder, but just a single ZIP file. You can send it like any other file. Where have you uploaded it to? A server you control? Where do you want to save it via SFTP? Programming questions, e.g. with PHP are off topic on Super User though. Please consider asking a more specific example with the code you're already using over on [SO].

Answer (score 1):

SFTP does not work for getting an entire directory/folder.  You should use SCP instead with the command: `scp -r user@host:/the/path/`